# Excluir pasta com permissão CHMOD777

Tags: php

Crio uma pasta com o PHP assim

```
mkdir('/public_html/buscauiva/public_html/'.$_POST['Nome'].'', 0777);
```

Para excluir estou usando o **rmdir()** do PHP

```
dir='/var/www/casamentowagnerecamila.com.br/public_html/buscauiva/public_html/'.$row['nome'].'';

if(rmdir($dir)) 
{
echo 'Pasta deletada com sucesso.';
}
else 
{
echo 'A pasta não pode ser deletada.';
}
```

Mais o PHP não consegue excluir a pasta retornando o erro:
 **A pasta não pode ser deletada.**

Como faço para excluir a pasta com o php ( contém arquivos dentro)?

Comment: quando cria a pasta você não precisa do caminho completo (`/var/www/casamentowagnerecamila.com.br`). Não pode remover isso na hora de excluir também?

Comment: sim eu fiz isso, mais retorna o erro A pasta não pode ser deletada

Comment: no `else`, imprime `error_get_last();` pra ver qual o erro real e coloca na pergunta, pode ser que ajude.

Comment: não retornou nenhum erro com o error_get_last();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para apagar uma pasta, é necessário primeiro apagar os arquivos dentro dela. Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
$dir='/var/www/casamentowagnerecamila.com.br/public_html/buscauiva/public_html/'.$row['nome'].'';

// Se a pasta não existir
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    echo "Pasta não existe";
}

// Se não for uma pasta, exclui o arquivo
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    unlink($dir);
}

// Verifica os arquivos dentro da pasta
foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
    unlink($item);
}

// Por fim, apaga a pasta
rmdir($dir);
```

De forma mais simplificada, você pode usar comandos do SO pra apagar a pasta, mas essa solução só funciona em LINUX (eu acho)

```
// chama o comando do SO
system('rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir), $retorno);
// esse comando linux retorna 0 quando sucesso
if( $retorno == 0) echo "Excluido com sucesso";
```

Answer (score 1):

Fui dar uma olhada no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rmdir.php) e vi que para deletar a pasta, *"o diretório tem que estar vazio e as permissões relevantes autorizarem a esta operação"*.

No próprio manual tem um exemplo de como proceder; você precisa *limpar* o diretório e depois deletá-lo, você usaria assim:

```
public static function MeuMetodo()
{
  // ...      
  dir='/var/www/casamentowagnerecamila.com.br/public_html/buscauiva/public_html/'.$row['nome'].'';

  if(DelTree($dir)) 
  {
    echo 'Pasta deletada com sucesso.';
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'A pasta não pode ser deletada.';
  }
}

public static function DelTree($dir) { 
  files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
  foreach ($files as $file) { 
    (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
  } 
  return rmdir($dir); 
}
```

Comment: com esse código não abre a página, está faltando alguma coisa